# Python's super() , what exactly happens?

Tags: python, super

I am trying to understand what objects are created when  we instantiate the child class in Python, for example:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

class ElectricCar(Car):
     def __init__(self, make, model, year):
          super().__init__(make, model, year)

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
```

When we create the object my_tesla, we instantiate the class ElectricCar by calling the constructor of this class, which in his turn calls the constructor of the parent. How does it happen? Right now I have two guesses:

1) super() is just the reference to the parent class, so we call the constructor of the parent by "super().**init**(make, model, year)" instantiating our child class. As a result we have just **ONE object** of our class ElectricCar().

2) super(), calls the constructor of the parent, create the object of the "Car" class, then we call the constructor of this object, by "super().**init**(make, model, year)". As a result we have **TWO objects**: one object of the class Car() and one object of the class ElectiricCar, in our case they are the same though.

Which one is correct?
If neither then please explain what exactly happens in the:

```
 super().__init__(make, model, year)
```

Comment: no. you still only have one object, an `ElectricCar`. a constructor is a function like any other. it doesn't "create" an object for you - by the time the constructor is executed, the object was already created by the underlying runtime. constructors are just there to INITIALIZE that new object. so calling super().__init__ just runs a plain object method. the fact that that method is a constructor is irrelevant. it's a constructor only when it's auto-executed by the object builder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__init__` isn't a constructor, it's an **initializer**. By the time `__init__` is called, the objects has already been constructed (via `__new__`). So you get only one object, but it's initialized twice - for example, `ElectricCar.__init__` may decide to re-initialize `self.model` after `Car.__init__` has been run.

When calling `super()`, the appropriate baseclass is looked up in the context of the current instance. Basically, `super().__init__(make, model, year)` could be rewritten as `Car.__init__(self, make, model, year)` in your example.

This is why in earlier versions of python, the call was actually `super(ElectricCar, self)` - it looks up the baseclass of the current class (`ElectricCar`) and uses the current instance (`self`) as if it were an instance of that class instead.

Note that initializing doesn't mean preparing the object, it means preparing the object's state. An object is fully functional even when it does not implement `__init__`.

---

To clarify: When you call `ElectricCar()`, what is actually executed is close to this:

```
that_object = ElectricCar.__new__()  # this will actually use object.__new__
if isinstance(that_object, ElectricCar):
    ElectricCar.__init__(that_object)
return that_object
```

That means you have *one* object from the call to `ElectricCar.__new__`. The call to `ElectricCar.__init__` will only modify/initialize that object. It may do so using other functions, such as `Car.__init__`.

Comment: so, the objects of the two classes are created in any case? and by:
    super().__init__(make, model, year) 
we just initialize our ElectricCar object? And as result we have one object of the Car class not initialized and an object of ElectricCar class initialized?

Comment: Only *one* object is created, namely when you call `ElectricCar()`. *That* object is then used as `that_object.__init__()`, which resolves to `ElectricCar.__init__(self=that_object)`, which uses super to call `Car.__init__(self=that_object)`.